# Calling C# WebService from Coldfusion and I cannot get results

Tags: c#, wcf, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion (9) function calling a self-hosted WCF C# WebService. I publish it to my Virtual Server, and call it from SoapUI and it works.

When I call it from ColdFusion using CFInvoke, I get a red box with a list of methods.

```html
<cfinvoke 
    webservice="http://dev-wcf/sideswebservice/SidesSelfHost.SidesWebService.svc?Wsdl"      
    method = "GetEmailsFor"
    returnVariable = "httpResponse"
   >
</cfinvoke>
<cfdump var="#httpResponse#">
```

[image: CFDump of CFInvoke result]

When I call it from ColdFusion using CFHTTP, I get xml with structure names, but no data.

```html
<cfhttp 
    url="http://dev-wcf/sideswebservice/SidesSelfHost.SidesWebService.svc?Wsdl"
    resolveurl="yes"
    method="GET"
    throwOnError="yes" 
>
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#cfhttp#">
```

[image: CFDump of CFHTTP Result]

I cannot help but think that how I receive the response in CF might have something to do with not getting my email record(s) data, since it works in the Soap UI.

**Update 1:**

Ah, I see a light at the end of the tunnel. When I try to dump getEaaempBin() though, it crashes and burns.

```
<cfset httpResponse = structNew()> 
<cfinvoke 
   webservice="dev-wcf/sideswebservice/…"; 
   method="GetEmailsFor" 
   returnVariable = "httpResponse"> 
</cfinvoke> 
<cfset getEmailRecord = structNew()> 
<cfset getEmailRecord = httpResponse.getEmailRecord()> 
<cfdump var="#getEmailRecord#"> 
<cfset getEaaempBin = structNew()> 
<!--- <cfset getEaaempBin = getEmailRecord.getEaaempBin()> 
      <cfdump var="#getEaaempBin#"> 
-->
```

[image: CFDump of getEmailRecord() Result]

**Update 2:**
This is my newest ColdFusion Code. The addresses are duplicates instead of the real data, which is 2 records.

```
<cfinvoke webservice="#wsdurl#" 
    method="GetEmailsFor" 
    returnVariable = "httpResponse"> 
   <cfinvokeargument name="bin" value="0000210883"/> 
   <cfinvokeargument name="population" value="0"/> 
</cfinvoke> 

<cfset getEmailRecord = httpResponse.getEmailRecord()> 
<cfdump var="#getEmailRecord[1].getEmailAddress()#"><br> 
<cfdump var="#getEmailRecord[2].getEmailAddress()#">
```

**Results:**

```
charlotte.d.williams@example.com
charlotte.d.williams@example.com
```

**Update 3:**

Turns out the duplicates were caused by the C# code. The only thing I did wrong (haven't done lists and data tables for 9 months) is instantiating a new record at the top of the loop... I added an instantiation for the record inside the loop, and now it works wonderful.

```
public List<EmailRecord> GetEmailsFor(string bin, Int32 population){
  EmailRecord emailRecord = new EmailRecord();
  List<EmailRecord> listEmailRecords = new List<EmailRecord>();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();

  //... populate DataTable

  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows){
        if (row["EAAEMP_BIN"] == DBNull.Value){
            emailRecord.EaaempBin = "";
        }
        else{
            emailRecord.EaaempBin = (string)row["EAAEMP_BIN"];
        }
        if (row["EMAIL_ADDRESS"] == DBNull.Value){
            emailRecord.EmailAddress = "";
        }
        else{
            emailRecord.EmailAddress = (string)row["EMAIL_ADDRESS"];
        }

        listEmailRecords.Add(emailRecord);
  }

  return listEmailRecords;
}
```

Comment: If you post the screenshots you'd like to display on a different site and respond to my comment I'll edit your post and include them.

Comment: They are here:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b2e09a13-8dde-4ae6-8cd0-fb5b4ce4c978/console-service-application-works-over-wcf-service-but-now-oracle-connection-breaks?forum=wcf

Comment: The result of the cfinvoke looks okay.  It is some sort of [wrapped array](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4337438). Based on the screen shot, try dumping `httpResponse.getEmailRecord()`. It should contain an array of `EmailRecord` objects. RE: *call it ...using CFHTTP* Because you are just retrieving the WSDL, not invoking a method of the web service.

Comment: BTW, can you update this question with the code snippets from the other thread? That way the question will still be meaningful even if the other link breaks or changes.

Comment: Add results of adding getEmailRecord (tried this weeks ago :()). Just get a list of more methods. Look at latest on msdn. Is that what you meant by code snippets of the other thread? Also, I tried dumping cfhttp.getEmailRecord() for CFHTTP and method was not found.

Comment: Also, I am calling a method. It is GetEmailsFor, which returns a list of email records. I will eventually pass it 2 parameters too.

Comment: *Just get a list of more methods* That is what should happen in this case. The result is an array of java objects. You need to loop through the array and call the appropriate methods on each object to retrieve the values.  The method names should follow the bean pattern. ie get*SomePropertyName*. *RE: Is that what you meant by code snippets of the other thread?* I meant post your CF code in this question :) S.O. discourages questions that depend on external content to be understood. Those kinds of questions are often closed.

Comment: Ah, I see a light at the end of the tunnel. When I try to dump getEaaempBin() though, it crashes and burns. 
<cfset httpResponse = structNew()>
<cfinvoke webservice = "http://dev-wcf/sideswebservice/SidesSelfHost.SidesWebService.svc?Wsdl" method = "GetEmailsFor" returnVariable = "httpResponse">
</cfinvoke>

<cfset getEmailRecord = structNew()>
<cfset getEmailRecord = httpResponse.getEmailRecord()>
<cfdump var="#getEmailRecord#">
<cfset getEaaempBin = structNew()>
<!--- 
<cfset getEaaempBin = getEmailRecord.getEaaempBin()>
<cfdump var="#getEaaempBin#">
-->

Comment: yay, I got data!!!! Thank you!

Comment: @CharlotteWilliams - please post your solution as an answer to this question. This will help other users.

Comment: *RE: try to dump getEaaempBin() though, it crashes*  BTW, that is because the method returns `void`.  In CF that equates to undefined ie null.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `cfinvoke` looks okay. The web service is just returning some sort of [wrapped array](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4337438). Try dumping `httpResponse.getEmailRecord()`. It should contain an array of `EmailRecord` objects.

> Add results of adding getEmailRecord ... Just get a list of more methods.

**Update:**

That is what should happen. The result is an array of java objects representing an email record. You need to loop through that array and call the appropriate methods on each object to retrieve the values. The method names should follow the bean pattern. ie get*SomePropertyName()*. The last image is a little blurry, so the method names may be off, but you get the idea ..

```
 for ( record in httpResponse.getEmailRecord() )
 {
     // call one of the methods to retrieve 
     //  the value for the given property
     writeDump( record.getVerificationText() );
 }
```

> When I call it from ColdFusion using CFHTTP, I get xml with structure
>   names, but no data

Side note, the reason for that is that your cfhttp call only retrieves the definition file ie WSDL. It does not invoke a method that returns data.

Comment: My darn parameters I am passing are now stopping it ... Web service operation GetEmailsFor with parameters {bin={0000210883},population={0}} cannot be found.                                 Do I need to pass the parms as SOAP? I will post the cost once all the kinks are worked out. :)   Here is the C# method description ... List<EmailRecord> GetEmailsFor(string bin, Int32 population);.                Also, when I get a list back, instead of 2 email records, it was the same one twice. Weird!

Comment: Can you update your question with your current code AND the signature from the web service itself? Just to make sure it's what you're thinking..

Comment: Very strange. I came in this morning and the errors for the parms is gone, lol. I have posted picks, though. Sorry, this editor does not allow for pics or carriage returns. Still have duplicate email records instead of 2 different records.... https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b2e09a13-8dde-4ae6-8cd0-fb5b4ce4c978/console-service-application-works-over-wcf-service-but-now-oracle-connection-breaks?forum=wcf#96b4b212-7cf1-47e3-b7b3-c86514dda948

Comment: Would that all issues were self-resolving ;-) Though sometimes a break away from the code is all you need. The editor does allow CR (though posting images probably requires a certain reputation level for new members).  As far as the duplicates, your CF code looks right. Did you first test the web service on the C# side? Verify it is not actually returning duplicate results.

Comment: I did verifiy C# code when it was just IIS and not Self Hosting. That is my next check though. It is easier to test the IIS part than it is to test the Self Hosting.

Comment: The only thing I did wrong (haven't done lists and data tables for 9 months) is instantiating a new record at the top of the loop. Everything is perfect now. The code is there, accept for the new record at the top of the loop.

Comment: (Edit) Ah, okay. So it was updating and adding the same object to the list multiple times.  Hence the duplicates. I take it you moved the instantiation (not declaration) inside the for loop and it works now, right?

Comment: I added an instantiation for the record inside the loop, and now it works wonderful. Thank god for your site, and you wonderful experts. :) Three other sites still have not responded at all.

Comment: (Edit) Great! Happy Friday :)  BTW, CF usually caches web service definitions.  So if you make changes to the web service, you will need to add `refreshWSDL="yes"` to your cfinvoke call to force CF to update the definitions. After it is refreshed, do not forget to remove it.